# Подключение в mssql по средствам Altova XMLSpy

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Потребовалось решить задачу генерации sql таблиц на основе xsd-схем.

Был выбран пакет Altova XMLspy, потому что больше аналогов не нашел.
Прежде чем Altova сможет сгенерить таблицы, надо подключиться к БД.

Используя это [оффициальное руководство](https://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spyenterprise/index.html?dbc_connecting_to_sql_server_ado.htm), когда я перехожу к пункту `3`, то сколько бы не нажимал refresh, окно возможных коннектов всегда пустое.

Почему он может не видеть подключения?

Comment: Например, не работает служба SQL Server Browser, достаточно просто ввести имя, вовсе не обязательно его выбирать

Comment: Туда нельзя ввести значение. Там только выбор по списку(